# In Safari Web Inspector, what does it mean when a variable/member is grayed?

Tags: javascript, debugging, safari, web-inspector

Here is a cropped screenshot of the Safari Web Inspector:

[image]

In this screenshot, why are `message`, `stack`, and `__proto__` grayed / faded?

Comment: I think it's because those properties are part of the prototype.

Comment: It's because that property is not holding any value. null/undefined all are treated as missing values. Safari is just showing you the type of attribute.